# Reading a Post request from a user HttpApplication

Tags: post, get, httpapplication

I've been messing about with 
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

Is there some way of the server identifying if the request is get or post.

Basically i want to create an if statement and if the 
request is a GET it jumps into the if statement, if its a post it doesnt.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Request.HttpMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) property.

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
if(app.Context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
{
  // Do stuff.
}
```